# ModelState.IsValid returns false for Ok Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using this ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using CardNumbers.Objects;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;

using DataAnnotationsExtensions;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace CardNumbers.Models
{
    public class ClientViewModel
    {
        public Client Client { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Editable(false)]
        [Column("ClientId", TypeName = "int")]
        public virtual int? ClientId
        {
            get
            {
                if (Client == null)
                    return null;
                else
                    return Client.Id;
            }

            set { Client.Id = value ?? 0; }
        }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Client No")]
        [UIHint("Number")]
        [Column("client_no", TypeName = "smallint")]
        [Remote("doesClientNoExist", "Client", HttpMethod = "POST",
            AdditionalFields = "ClientId",
            ErrorMessage = "Client Number already exists. Please enter a different Client Number.")]
        public virtual Int16 Number
        {
            get
            {
                if (Client == null)
                    return 0;
                else
                    return Client.Number;
            }

            set { Client.Number = value; }
        }

        [Required]
        [Column("client_name", TypeName = "varchar")]
        [DisplayName("Client Name")]
        [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Client Name should not be longer than 30 characters")]
        [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Client Name is too short")]
        [Remote("doesClientNameExist", "Client", HttpMethod = "POST", AdditionalFields = "ClientId",
            ErrorMessage = "Client Name already exists. Please enter a different Client Name.")]
        public virtual string Name
        {
            get
            {
                if (Client == null)
                    return "";
                else 
                    return Client.Name;            
            }

            set { Client.Name = value; }
        }

        public int id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The reason I had to expose two Client properties through public properties of the model is that I am trying to use RemoteValidator. Anyway, I enter both required fields Name and number and then trying to save the model and it's returning ModelState.IsValid false. How can I see what is wrong? I am attempting to use jquery modal dialog so it's not very simple to reload.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am thinking - could it be that I need to use some base class or interface for the model?

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint and see what is contained within ModelState.Errors.

Comment: Or you can comment out sets of attributes, to narrow down, which one invalidates the model.

Comment: Have you tried ngm's idea?

Comment: I am going to try that again but I think I saw 0 errors. Let me re-try

Comment: If I type in the immediate window ModelState. it doesn't have Errors at all. It has Count which is 13. I don't know what it is

Comment: ModelState does not contain Errors property. So, how should I see what is wrong? I checked that model.Client.Number and model.Client.Name contains correct values which I entered

Comment: I added the following
 var errors = ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors.Select(z => z.Exception));  and found that it returned Count =1 and 0: null How does it help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42439592/modelstate-isvalid-returns-false-only-when-resource-language-changed